# How to use primary key in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i'm having trouble using incrementing even if i set it to false laravel tries to use a numeric key

using postgree

```
$atividade = Atividade::whereServicoId('14.01')->first();
```

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
> LINE 1: select * from "servicos" where "servicos"."id" **in (11)**
> ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "servicos" where "servicos"."id" **in (11))**

```
<?php

class Atividade extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $with = ['servico'];
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'descricao'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function servico(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Servico::class, 'servico_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

class Servico extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'descricao'];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

Comment: Laravel has **no** built-in `Model`method called `whereServicoId(...)`. Did you intend to use `find(...)`? [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: Did you mean to use `$atividade = Atividade::firstWhere('servico_id', '14.01');`  ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will helps you

```
$invoices = Atividade::with(array('servico' => function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', '14.01');
}))->first();
```

Comment: solution
protected $keyType = "string";
public $incrementing = false;